# Node JS Require undefined functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

In writing modular JavaScript code for the first time (slowly converting from Java server code to Node JS), I'm having trouble understanding why this code doesn't work.

Node Server code:

```
const wceTimer = require('./myTimer');

const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server running at http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/');
    console.log(typeof wceTimer);
    console.log(typeof wceTimer.getTime);
});
```

Here is my module code:

```
    var myTimer = (function (){

    var currentTimeMS = -1;
    var timerInterval;

    function getTime(){
        return currentTime;
    }

    function getTimeFormatted(){
        if(currentTime <= 0) {
            return "undefined";
        } else {
            return new Date(currentTimeMS).toUTCString();
        }
    }

    function advanceTime(){
        if(currentTime <= 0) {
            this.currentTimeMS = 946684800000;
        } else {
            this.currentTimeMS = this.currentTimeMS + 1000;
        }
    }

    function startTimer(){
        timerInterval = setInterval(advanceTime, 3000);
    }

    function stopTimer(){
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
    }

    return {
        startTimer: startTimer,
        stopTimer: stopTimer,
        getTime: getTime,
        getTimeFormatted: getTimeFormatted
    };

})();
```

Why does line 3 in the server.listen method fail with undefined?
Why cannot I use the developer console in my browser to call functions on myTimer?

Comment: `module.exports` - https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html. And while it doesn't really make a difference, you don't need the IIFE anymore as all of your module code is already contained within it's own scope.

Comment: You need export `myTimer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module doesn't export anything:

```
module.exports = myTimer;
```

Comment: This is how you export Commonjs modules, which are the modules in Node.js